# Mutable static variable across multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading, static-members

I'm learning about threads in Java right now, along with all the concepts and keywords.  I just learned the `volatile` keyword, and it raised some interesting questions in my mind for a project I'm working on.  Say I have a class called `Connector` with a field like this:

```
    public static String DEFAULT_CONNECTION_TYPE = "UDP";
```

Say I'll be making lots of `Connector` objects on multiple threads, but each thread will be using different connection methods (like "TCP").  On the threads that will be using other connection types, if I don't want to explicitly declare it for every object, is there a way to change the `DEFAULT_CONNECTION_TYPE` on each thread?  Is there a keyword that will make a variable thread-local, yet still static across that thread?  Does that even make sense?

Comment: Please don't use mutable statics, even thread-globals!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do not recommend changing a static variable from multiple threads just to avoid carrying it in the class instance, but if that's what you want to do, see [ThreadLocal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html).

The right way to do this is to make the connection type an instance field:

```
enum ConnectionType { UDP, TCP; }

class Connector {

    private static final ConnectionType DEFAULT_CONNECTION_TYPE = 
        ConnectionType.UDP;

    private final ConnectionType connectionType;

    public Connector(ConnectionType connectionType) {
        this.connectionType = connectionType;
    }

    public Connector() {
        this(DEFAULT_CONNECTION_TYPE);
    }
}
```

Comment: This example is good.  There's no reason to use a ThreadLocal here.

Answer (score 1):

Check out ThreadLocal: http://java.dzone.com/articles/java-thread-local-%E2%80%93-how-use

Answer (score 1):

Check out [ThreadLocal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html)